# FindInstance specifying reals increases the time significantly and gives errors

Tags: matrix, findinstance

I was wondering if there is any way to put time constraint on FindInstance.

My problem is as follows: I want to find two, $2 \times 2$ matricies $A,B$ given $Tr(A)$, $Tr(B)$, $TR(AB)$, $Det(A)$ and $Det(B)$. It is not clear to me there is an easy formula for $A,B$ given these numbers. Hence I resorted to using FindInstance to find $A,B$. However, I want $A,B$ to be real. The problem is, whenever I enforce the domain of reals, the length of computations gets extended immensely. Not only that but I get errors like "Divide","Infionity" and "GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList" which never happens when I do not specify the domain.

In short, how can I perhaps put a time constraint on FindInstance, so that after a while, it simply gives up?

Here is the "code" I am using:

```
FindInstance[
 k1 + k4 == a && m1 + m4 == b && k1*m1 + k2*m3 + k3*m2 + k4*m4 == c &&
   k1*k4 - k2*k3 == e && m1*m4 - m2*m3 == d, {k1, k2, k3, k4, m1, m2, 
  m3, m4}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

I was asked for an example where this takes forever, here is one:

```
a=-1.66556
b=1.59615
c=-9.37364
d=5.69929
e=5.67953
```

Thank you

Comment: You have 8 unknowns but only 5 equations.

Comment: @DanielHuber that's only a problem if you want to solve it - in this case they just want to find an instance. e.g you don't need more than one equation to find an instance where x+y+z == 0

Comment: Can you give an example where it goes slowly? I'm using 12.3.1 and I've only seen a 1-2s delay using this for various parameters: `A = Array[a, {2, 2}]; B = Array[b, {2, 2}];
ta = -82; tb = 74; tab = 13; da = -14; db = 64;
eqns = Tr[A] == ta && Tr[B] == tb && Det[A] == da && Det[B] == db && 
   Tr[A . B] == tab;
{Ar, Br} = {A, B} /. First[FindInstance[eqns, Variables[{A, B}], Reals]]` You could always try `TimeConstrained` to break the evaluation.

Comment: @flinty I edited the question to include an example that takes forever and gives a bunch of errors. I thought timesconstrained would not work as I do not want to abort an entire Do loop I have but it seems that does not happen right? If i do timeconstrained inside a loop it does not abort the loop but rather evaluating the expression. Though I would have to now implement an if statement, if aborted then do nothing. Am I correct?

Comment: @2132123 you can get `TimeConstrained` to return anything you want upon hitting the timeout, e.g `TimeConstrained[Do[i^2, {i, 10000000}], 1, 999]` will return 999 if it times out.

Comment: @2132123 also I was thinking if you're okay with numerical solutions: `A = Array[a, {2, 2}]; B = Array[b, {2, 2}]; ta = -1.66556; tb = 1.59615; tab = -9.37364; da = 5.67953; db = 5.69929; eqns = {Tr[A] == ta, Tr[B] == tb, Det[A] == da, 
  Det[B] == db, Tr[A . B] == tab};
objective = Total[(eqns /. Equal -> Subtract)^2];
{err, sol} = NMinimize[objective, Variables[{A, B}], 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]`  will give a solution very quickly - you just need to check that `err` is very small before accepting the answer. In your example the err is quite large so maybe it can't be solved.

Comment: `Solve` on this system indicates there are no real solutions.